# How can I create a stun gun in Unreal?

Tags: c++, software-engineering, unreal

I am fairly new to the programming world. I am currently at college and one of the tasks I need to do is create a "stun gun" or "freeze gun."

Basically, when you shoot a target (another player) I want it to stop them for five or so seconds. The gun will do no damage to the player, just simply freezes them. The player can be refrozen and/or continuously shot to remain frozen until the shooter's ammo runs out.

If anyone can give me some help on what to call in certain classes, or even provide me with the basic code the will freeze the player for several seconds, I'll be very thankful.

I know how to make a new weapon, and change fire-rates, etc... I am just stuck with what it is I have to do to freeze a player using the projectile class, or pawn class?

Comment: Sorry for those who want to know the version of udk I am currently using, it is: UDK-2015-01

Comment: The player needs a frozen timer variable. If the variable is above 0 decrease it by Delta time. When you hit a player with the weapon, you need to set the frozen timer variable to the number of seconds you want them to be frozen..    Lastly, before any player  movement, you have to make sure the freeze variable is 0 or lower. If not, don't move

Comment: Ah yes, Thank-you. But Do you know how to code this? Cause I still cant figure it out.

Comment: Coding should really be your job otherwise you are going to ask the exact same question on your next homework assignment. @DanielHolst nailed it for you. On hit you increase the frozen timer of the player it hits. You do not move the player until the frozen timer hits `<= 0` again.

Comment: Other then that you could ask or google how to effect a variable of a target hit by a gun which in UDK I do not know the answer about. Now you should know how to increase a variable like `int freezeTimer` on a player by getting shot. If you made a good attempt but still have undesired behavious then you can post your issue including code and people here are much more willing to do a bit of coding for you and help you on your way.

Comment: when I choose my job, it wont involve programming, so i just want to get through this @Menno, but thanks :) Um I have searched Google, though I haven't even created the gun yet, I just need to know if its like
`Function Freeze (actor other) 
if pawn HitBy ('My custom projectile') 
then pawn.groundspeed set 0 for x seconds`


thats what im aiming for, and i just cant figure out the right way to code it. 

as for google, the only resource related to this is the UDN forums, which is currently down and has been for about a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I decided to help you on your way. But we are simply not doing homework for you. UDK documentation seems down for maintainance but I have found this: http://www.moug-portfolio.info/udk-projectiles/ example. You should read it completely since it helps you understand projectiles. Towards the bottom they explain projectiles. Let it be clear that I have no experience other then creating some simple maps a decade ago with UDK.

The code I found on the mentioned website that I will be discussing:

```
class SandboxPaintballProjectile extends UDKProjectile;

simulated function ProcessTouch(Actor Other, Vector HitLocation, Vector HitNormal)
{
    if ( Other != Instigator )
    {
        WorldInfo.MyDecalManager.SpawnDecal ( DecalMaterial'SandboxContent.Materials.DM_Paintball_Splash', HitLocation, rotator(-HitNormal), 128, 128, 256, false, FRand() * 360, none );
        Other.TakeDamage( Damage, InstigatorController, Location, MomentumTransfer * Normal(Velocity), MyDamageType,, self);
        Destroy();
    }
}

simulated event HitWall(vector HitNormal, actor Wall, PrimitiveComponent WallComp)
{
    Velocity = MirrorVectorByNormal(Velocity,HitNormal); //That's the bounce
    SetRotation(Rotator(Velocity));
    TriggerEventClass(class'SeqEvent_HitWall', Wall);
}

DefaultProperties
{
    Begin Object Name=CollisionCylinder
        CollisionRadius=8
        CollisionHeight=16
    End Object

    Begin Object Class=DynamicLightEnvironmentComponent Name=MyLightEnvironment
        bEnabled=TRUE
    End Object

    Components.Add(MyLightEnvironment)

    begin object class=StaticMeshComponent Name=BaseMesh
        StaticMesh=StaticMesh'SandboxContent.Meshes.SM_PaintBall'
        LightEnvironment=MyLightEnvironment
    end object

    Components.Add(BaseMesh)

    Damage=25
    MomentumTransfer=10
}
```

My first assumption is that if you create a weapon with a projectile you have this script attached to it. I simply cannot help you with that.

As Mougli talks about this he explains that if a wall or actor with `bWorldGeometry set to true` the `HitWall` function/method will be triggered. Since we are not freezing walls or furniture we will leave that alone. Whenever another actor get's hit the `ProcessTouch` is being called and like I already mentioned you are supplied by the actor that actually is hit `Actor other`.

Now we can call that actor and do stuff with it by doing `other.doStuff`. So we want to increment a freeze variable? Then we need to supply this variable first too this actor. So first we need the script actor script.

Let's assign a variable `public int freezeCounter = 0f` on top.

Now we can access that variable from the `ProcessTouch` method and alter it. `other.freezeCounter = 2000` in milliseconds. Whenever an actor is hit he gets his `freezeCounter` set to 2000.

Now we need to make sure the actor is not able to move. We could wrap all the actors actions in a if statement stating `if (freezeCounter <= 0)` and he will be frozen for it's entire life. The last step is to decrease the `freezeCounter` by the amount of miliseconds since the last frame often called something like deltaTime.

The best lesson you should learn from this is to break down your problem into small steps. Try to define these steps and look around on Google for answers, like I did for the `Projectile Collision`.

However there might be a view catches. I'm not sure what the definition of actor is in UDK but basically anything that can be hit seems to be an actor. You might have to check in the `ProcessTouch` method if an actualy player or character has been hit. Again I do not know the naming conventions but if you open a players script and it says something like `class Character extends Actor` then you can add the variable to the `Player` script. But then you will not be able to use `other.freezeCounter = xxxx`. Now you need to cast it:

if (other instanceof Character) //check if the actor is a character
{
    (Player)other.freezeCounter = 2000; //cast other as a player and alter freezeCounter
}

This should get you on your way, otherwise I strongly suggest you tell your teacher to learn you the basics of programming first before telling you to code in a engine you barely know and afaik is pretty much obsolete (could be wrong on my last statement).